# Is this a text-indent bug in Chrome and IE, or I am missing something?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, text-indent

http://jsfiddle.net/CtaBe/

I've tested this in FF, Chrome and IE. Only FF shows the intended behavior (or at least what I think is the intended behavior). Chrome and IE show the same behavior: when you first focus on the input, the cursor doesn't indent. After you type somehing, delete it, and re-focus, it indents properly.

How can I fix this? Because I want to display an image at that indented space.

Comment: Why not use a `padding-left` on that input instead of `text-indent`?

Comment: @artyom: because `padding-left` is not `text-indent`.

Comment: @Omeid Herat if the OP simply wants to indent the text in order to use a background image on the input, I'd go with `padding-left`, as seen [here](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/?whichTipsAndTricks=input-with-background).

Comment: ah yes, a simple padding-left, how I forgot that. I don't know the difference between padding-left and text-indent, but at least it solves my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Artyom: `padding-left` for `text-indent` in CSS is like `table` for Layout in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

*Quick disclaimer: this message outlines a solid example of why a person would choose to use text-indent on an input field rather than padding. It does not answer "how to fix IE handle text-indent on input fields"*

The thing about padding-left is that it alters the width of your input field, which can be undesirable.

Imagine a scenario where you wish to show a background-image icon for the following states of your inputs' data:

- required field
- invalid input
- missed required field
- password strength

In such a scenario, we'd need to nudge the text away from the left border to display the icon (which is a much simpler feat than going for the right side, but that's a whole other discussion. If we use padding, the width of the input field changes. That's not ideal, since the various "states" can change.

For instance, maybe a field is only required based on the value of another field. When that field "becomes" required the field "grows" according whatever padding we apply to move the text away from the icon, via relevant class. That's far from elegant, especially when other fields are floated next to it.

Furthermore, in the case of textareas, we wouldn't want to pad the entire side - the first line would suffice.

That's exactly where using text-indent comes into play. And it works great - except in Internet explorer. Which is what has led me here, as I search for other ideas or solutions. I have a few ideas in mind but hopefully there's something simpler that I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, this is a [known issue](http://crbug.com/53466). Please star it :)

Comment: Thanks! I was going to ask where to file the bug for it.

Answer (score 0):

'text-indent' applies to block-level elements, table cells and inline blocks. I hope you are using it on a not block-level element.